# how to get content into array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm using free API services to provide me informations about location of IPs
and here is the code i'm using

```
$api = file_get_contents('http://api_site.com?ip=XX.XX.XX.XX');
// WHERE XX.XX.XX.XX Is IP and api_site.com is my provider
```

The output is as following (this is on me)

```
OK;XX.XX.XX.XX;EG;EGYPT;AL QAHIRAH;CAIRO;+02:00
// ok , IP , Country code , Country , Region , City , Time zone GMT
```

Now how to get the following output into array so i can easily show it up
I've used the following code.

```
$api = file_get_contents('http://api_site.com?ip=XX.XX.XX.XX');
$info = array_shift(explode(";", api));
$message = "$info";
// Output is just "OK"
//OK;XX.XX.XX.XX;EG;EGYPT;AL QAHIRAH;CAIRO;+02:00
// I want get all sperated
```

so is there any way i can explode by `;` and get all and be able to show up
~ thanks

Comment: well you just answered yourself.. use explode()

Comment: Why do you use `array_shift()`?

Comment: @Juhana well, ummm that is very good question :| didn't the output shows +02:00 GMT ! morning stupidity :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why are you using `array_shift`?
that function will return the first element of the array removing it from the array itself.
This shoul be enough:

```
$api = file_get_contents('http://api_site.com?ip=XX.XX.XX.XX');
$info = explode(";", $api);
```

if you want to print out the results all together the you need to use `implode` function, which has the same parameters as `explode`

Answer (score 1):

You only need to explode. Don't use array_shift at all. Here's an example:

```
$info = explode(";", api);
$message = spritnf('Country: %s', $info[3]);
```